# .SQL Script including path to my local machine?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've a database on my laptop (within SQL Server 2008 r2) that I need to generate a .SQL script so I can upload it to my database on my ISP (via their website control panel).

I had a quick peek at the script that was generated, and it has some code pointing to my local drive.

Is this correct?  I'm sure there should be no reference to my local drive, if I'm going to put this script on my ISP and run it.

Example:

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [Chinatowndb]    Script Date: 03/06/2013 15:27:54 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [Chinatowndb] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'chinatowndb', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\chinatowndb.mdf' , SIZE = 3072KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'chinatowndb_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\chinatowndb_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Chinatowndb] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [Chinatowndb].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Chinatowndb] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Chinatowndb] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
...
...
...
```

I'm a novice so any advice from SQL experts who know about this would be greatly received.
Thanks
Tea,

Answer (score 0):

the FILENAME  is an optional parameter, if you no set the sql create that files on default path, here the definition http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx